# Pass search results data from one page to another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm populating search results to my page below - site visitors input keywords into my search bar to search Users, and results are generated on this page. Upon finding a matching result, the data for the user is populated into the below divs. That said, when a visitor clicks the "Go" button (go.png), I want the data retrieved to post on the following page (book.html.erb) inside of the same layout. How do I pass the data from _user.html.erb to book.html.erb?

**_user.html.erb**

```
<div class="card">

    <div class="columns">

        <div class="col">

  <%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => 'round-image-125' %>

<br><br>
<font color="#ee4d50" font size="3"><b>Services:</b>

        </div>


          <div class="col">


             <div class="name">
          <%= link_to user.firstname, user %> <%= user.lastname %> <a href="users/book"><img src="/assets/go.png" style="float:right; padding-right:15px" border="0"></a>


    </div>
        <br>
          <font color="#4d4d4d" font size="3"><b><%= user.city%>, <%= user.stateprov%></font></b>

         <br><br>
         <font color="#2c78d3" font size="4"><b>Bio:</b></font> 

        <br><br>
         <%= user.bio%>


         <br><br>
         <font color="#2c78d3" font size="4"><b>Categories:</b></font>   

</div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

**user/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="browse-subheader">

    <% if @user.present? %>
      <%= render @user %>
    <% else %>
      <p>There are no posts containing the term(s) <%= params[:search] %>.</p>
    <% end %>
```

**book.html.erb**

```
<div class="card">

        <div class="columns">

            <div class="col">

      <%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => 'round-image-125' %>

    <br><br>
    <font color="#ee4d50" font size="3"><b>Services:</b>

            </div>


              <div class="col">


                 <div class="name">
              <%= link_to user.firstname, user %> <%= user.lastname %> <a href="users/book"><img src="/assets/go.png" style="float:right; padding-right:15px" border="0"></a>


        </div>
            <br>
              <font color="#4d4d4d" font size="3"><b><%= user.city%>, <%= user.stateprov%></font></b>

             <br><br>
             <font color="#2c78d3" font size="4"><b>Bio:</b></font> 

            <br><br>
             <%= user.bio%>


             <br><br>
             <font color="#2c78d3" font size="4"><b>Categories:</b></font>   

    </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "You signed up successfully"
    flash[:color] = "valid"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
    flash[:color] = "invalid"
    render "new"
  end
end


def index
  @user = User.all
  if params[:search]
    @user = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @user = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end

  def book

  @user = User.new
  @category = Category.new

  end


def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

redirect_to @user  

else

  render 'edit'
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your controller Book action is not looking for the user found on the _user view. It is creating a new one instead.

Try replacing :

```
@user = User.new
```

by :

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Also make reference to the instance variable by adding the @ sign before the user variable in your book view. Such as @user.lastname instead of user.lastname (if I am not mistaken, user scope is only the view, as @user scope spans across view and controller)

Comment: Hi! So when I make your changes above, run my application and click on the "Go" button, I get the following error when I land on my book.html.erb: "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#book, Couldn't find User with 'id'=" I assume this is because it's not grabbing the found user's id? How might I fix this?

Comment: Does your _user.html.erb view already shows the correct user with lastname and name next to the go button ?

Comment: Ok I am sorry. You need to go deeper into the routing in order to pass data to the book action if this is what you want to do. Unlike the show action, where the ID is passed to the controller with the appropriate link_to helper automatically, this is not the case with a custom action. Why dont you try to render the partial view _user.html.erb inside the book view instead ? just replace everything in your book.html.erb file with <%= render 'user' %>

Comment: Even if i replace everything in book.html.erb with <%= render 'user' %>, I still get the same error: "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#book, Couldn't find User with 'id'=" Should I try linking to the book page with link_to?

Comment: What is the parent view where _user.htm.erb is rendered ? _user.html.erb is a partial that can't be displayed on it's own, but rendered inside another view. If you can see the name and lastnames, you probably have the right bit of codes in the parent view and parent controllers.. which we can mimick on the book controller.

Comment: I believe index.html.erb is the parent view, as it's where I render @user data for the partial - see above code edit.

Comment: Ok just copy the code inside the index action to the book action, removing the previous @user = User.find(params[:id]) reference. This should work. Yet you should definitely rethink your code. I don't know the purpose of this book action. But it seems you are trying to add a function to your user controller that does'nt seem right and may need a complete rethinking of the app. (adding a book controller instead, with a book model etc ..)

Comment: Ok, if I do that, it half works. I've pasted <% = render 'user' %> into my book page now, but it returns ALL users, lol not just the one returned via search on _user.html.erb? On the other hand, if I use my original divs/html to display the returned data on book, I get the error: undefined method `firstname' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8f75a10f20> (even after I copy the index action to book action).

Comment: But showing a single user is what the show action is made for. Why have you created a book action that just duplicates with the show action ? Does the show action and show view have a specific function you don't want to alter ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104125/discussion-between-brittany-and-maxence).